# Get largest structure (Canny Edge Detection)?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, vector, edge-detection

I am using the library found at this link: https://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

I implemented Image.h and Image.mm and I get the Canny Edge Detection filter by using this code:

```
- (IBAction)findEdges {
    ImageWrapper *greyScale=Image::createImage(_sourceImage, _sourceImage.size.width/4, _sourceImage.size.height/4);
    ImageWrapper *edges=greyScale.image->gaussianBlur().image->cannyEdgeExtract(0.4,0.6);
    // show the results
    UIImage *newimageView = edges.image->toUIImage();
    _imageView.image = newimageView;
}
```

Now I notice there is a method called `findLargestStructure`. This is that method:

```
void Image::findLargestStructure(std::vector<ImagePoint> *maxPoints) {
    // process the image
    std::vector<ImagePoint> points;
    points.reserve(10000);
    for(int y=0; y<m_height; y++) {
        for(int x=0; x<m_width; x++) {
            // if we've found a point in the image then extract everything connected to it
            if((*this)[y][x]!=0) {
                extractConnectedRegion(x, y, &points);
                if(points.size()>maxPoints->size()) {
                    maxPoints->clear();
                    maxPoints->resize(points.size());
                    std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), maxPoints->begin());
                }
                points.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is**, what exactly does this method do and how can I call it/use it from Objective C code? Pretty much my goal in the end of all of this is to use the Canny Edge Detection this library has and derive a CGRect somehow out of it by using the average of the biggest structure's edge points and then use that in my app.

So will the above method return a vector of those points or not? I am familiar with Objective-C but I am not that great with C++.

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: to call c++ function from objective c you have to convert your .m file as .mm file after this you can call this method

Comment: Yes, I have done so and that is not the issue. The issue I am having is how do I ACTUALLY call it from Objective C code. And my other issue is understanding the method properly and doing what I need to achieve (that I specified in the bottom of the question).

Answer (score 0):

The code is not compatible with Objective C since it uses C++ types in the interface, namely `std::vector<>`.

The code calls `extractConnectedRegion` on a number of points, and tries to return the largest result. There are some minor nitpicks: e.g. the assignment to `maxPoints` would have been much better done as `maxPoints = points`. (You can do even better, but that becomes unobvious)